# How to run PHP with vscode

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code, http-status-code-405

I'm trying to create a simple HTML form that redirects users to a thank you message displayed by the server, and written in PHP. However, nothing I do seems to work. I get a 405 every time I try to run the code. If I refresh the page it starts downloading. I'm using the live server extension and I have PHP installed.

HTML file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "styles-signup.css">
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "script-signup.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1 class = "title"></h1>
    </div>
    <div class = "form">
        <h1 id = "header">Create Your Account</h1>
        <form method = "POST" id = "signup" action = "action.php">
            <input name = "firstName" type = "text" placeholder="First Name" required id = "fname">
            <input name = "lastName" type = "text" placeholder = "Last Name" required id = "lname">
            <input name = "Email" type = "email" placeholder="email, e.g. person@gmail.com" required id = "mail">
            <input name = "newPassword" type = "password" id = "password" placeholder="Password" required minlength="8" maxlength="25">
            <input name = "passwordConfirm" type = "password" placeholder = "Confirm Password" required minlength="8" maxlength="25" id = "cpassword">
           <br>

           <input name = "gender" type = "radio" id = "male" required>
           <label for = "gender" id = "mlabel">Male</label>

           <input name = "gender" type = "radio" id = "female" required>
           <label for = "gender" id = "flabel">Female</label>

           <input name = "gender" type = "radio" id = "other" required>
           <label for = "gender" id = "olabel">Other</label>
           <br>

           <br>
           <input name = "birthdate" type = "number" min = "1920" max = "2019" placeholder="Year Of Birth" id = bd required>
           <br>

            <input name = "terms" type ="checkbox" id = "box" required>

            <p id = "tc">I agree to the <a href = "termsandconditions.txt" id = "tcLink">Terms and Conditions</a></p>

            <input name = "submit" type = "Submit" id = "button" value = "Sign up">

            <a href = "login.html" id = "login">Already have an account? Log in</a>

        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <?php
    echo "<p>Hi</p>";
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

I get this error:

[image: Error:]

Comment: Welcome. It's impossible to help you without any code. You will have to narrow down the problem on your end and then provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: VSCode is just an editor. It cannot execute your PHP code. You need PHP executable to execute it.

Comment: What platform are you using currently, Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### There is an Issue with this Question

---

VS Code is not a server, it is a highly specialized editor. In a nushell, this means that you cannot use it to accept HTTP request, and then preprocess those request using an executable. The reason that is a problem is because, PHP will not just work without being able to run its executable, but at its very core, the very essence of what PHP is, is an executable (with some libraries included).

#### SO I Can't use VS Code to write PHP?

Well, you can, but you will need to set up a development server that you will send requests to from VSCode. In other words, when you execute a PHP document in the browser, what the browser does, is it sends that script to your server, your server preprocesses the php document, and responds with an HTML document that was dynamically created using your initial PHP script. So, you will need a server ***(we call these development servers)*** that you can send your code to while it is in development, so you can see what your are creating, as you write it. There are extensions offered in the **[Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode)** that can help. Currently the most popular extension is a GUI server called...

#### [Open PHP/HTML/JS In Browser](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PrimaFuture.open-php-html-js-in-browser)

The link above takes you to the extensions page in the VS-Marketplace, but it's easiest to just install it from inside of VS   Code using [VS Code's in-editor extension view.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace)

You will also have to have PHP installed correctly, which is beyond the scope of this answer, but if you need help with that, **[this is a really great guide](https://kinsta.com/blog/install-php/)** that covers installing PHP on any platform, and any server.

Comment: When I have downloaded xampp on windows do I need to do any additional configuration to Vs code to make it work?

Comment: VS code is just an editor, it does not parse or interpret code, so no you do not have to do anything extra to VS-Code. You have to build your project inside the XAMPP Root directory to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I am highjacking this rather old and answered thread to present a far more comfortable method of running/testing your php projects from inside VSC that does not require you to run a XAMPP setup.

There is a VSCode extension called [PHP Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=brapifra.phpserver) that lets you serve your project to a temporary server. Of course you will need to have (depending on your project requirement) e.g. a MySQL server running as well but it's a great tool that helped me enormously, especially since I can place my project anywhere I want on my disk without having to take into account apache.