# Status code 405 (method not allowed) trying to save canvas into database

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, database

I'm currently trying to save canvas to database.

The program starts with a pre-loaded image on canvas, then user can draw on it and hitting "Save" would save the edited canvas to database. I have made an api folder, which in it consists of db.php (to connect to database using PDO), insertDrawing.php (to save edited canvas to database) and viewDrawing (to call saved canvases from database).

I use AJAX to POST canvas into database but when I run it, Network console from the Inspect Element shows error 405 (Method not Allowed): [Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqXwR.png)

I have tried almost everything regarding status 405 but it's to no avail.

These are my codings:

```js
window.onload = () => {
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    const saveButton = document.getElementById('save');
    const clearButton = document.getElementById('clear');
  
    new Drawing(canvas, saveButton, clearButton);
  };
  
  class Drawing {
    constructor(canvas, saveButton, clearButton) {
      this.isDrawing = false;
  
      canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', () => this.startDrawing());
      canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => this.draw(event));
      canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', () => this.stopDrawing());
  
      saveButton.addEventListener('click', () => this.save());
      clearButton.addEventListener('click', () => this.erase());
  
      const img = new Image();
      img.src = 'images/bodies.png';
      img.onload = () => {
        const canvas = this.canvas;
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      };
  
      const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  
      this.offsetLeft = rect.left;
      this.offsetTop = rect.top;
  
      this.canvas = canvas;
      this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
  
    }
    startDrawing() {
      this.isDrawing = true;
    }
    stopDrawing() {
      this.isDrawing = false;
    }
    draw(event) {
      if (this.isDrawing) {
        this.context.fillRect(event.pageX - this.offsetLeft, event.pageY - this.offsetTop, 3, 3);
        this.context.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
      }
    }
    save() {
      const imgdata = this.canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      const a = document.createElement('a');
      // a.href = imgdata;
      // a.download = 'image.png';
      a.click();

      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: 'api/insertDrawing.php',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: imgdata,
      });
    }
    erase(){
        const img = new Image();
        img.src = 'images/bodies.png';
        img.onload = () => {
            const canvas = this.canvas;
            const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        };
    }
  }
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css1.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="500" style="border: 1px solid;"></canvas>

    <button id="save" type="button">
      Save
    </button>
    <button id="clear" type="button">
      Clear
    </button>
    <!-- <input type="file" id="load" name="avatar" accept="image/png"> -->

    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="js1.js"></script> -->
    <script src="trytry.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Note: jQuery 3.2.1 has been added as a js file in the same folder

Whereas my php files look like this:

```php
<?php
   header('Content-Type: application/json');
   
   require_once('db.php');

   class Drawing 
   {
      var $image;
   }

   try
   {
      $selectAllDrawing->execute();      
      $row_count = $selectAllDrawing->rowCount(); 
         
      if ($row_count) 
      {
         $data = array();
             
         while($row = $selectAllDrawing->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
         {           
            //create Drawing object
            //put std drawing in Model (Drawing Object)
            $drawing = new Drawing();
            $drawing->image = $row['image'];
              
            array_push($data, $drawing);
         }
             
         echo json_encode($data);
         exit;
      } 
      else 
      {
         $data = array();
         echo json_encode($data);
         exit;
      }
   }
   catch(PDOException $e) 
   {
       die('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
   }
```

```php
<?php
    require_once('db.php');
    
    $image = $_POST["image"];
    
    //insert into database
    try 
    {
        $insertDrawing->execute(array(
            "image" => "$image", 
        ));
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) 
    {
        $errorMessage = $e->getMessage();
        $data = Array(
            "insertStatus" => "failed",
            "errorMessage" => $errorMessage
        );  
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
    }
    
    $data = Array(
        "insertStatus" => "success",
        "image" => $image,
    );
    
    echo json_encode($data);
```

```php
<?php
    //PDO
    function dbStart($address, $login, $password) 
    {
        try 
        {
            $db = new PDO($address, $login, $password);
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);    
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        } 
        catch(PDOException $e) 
        {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }   
        
        return $db;
    }

    function prepareDbStatement($db,
                                       &$insertDrawing,
                                       &$viewDrawing
                                       )
    {
        try 
        {       
            $insertContactStmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO drawing(image) VALUES (:image)");        
            
            $selectAllContactsStmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM drawing
                                                            ORDER BY image ASC'); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $e) 
        {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();  
        }   
    }

    $address = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=draw;charset=utf8';
    $login = "root";
    $password = "";
    $db = null;
    $db = dbStart(  $address, 
                    $login, 
                    $password);
                  
    $insertDrawing = null;
    $viewDrawing = null;
        
    //*                
    prepareDbStatement($db,
                           $insertDrawing,
                           $viewDrawing);
    //*/
```

Replies are kindly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: your server side isn't allowing "POST" method, perhaps there's something in the server side logs to show more info

Comment: Are you sure it's a PHP server you've got running on port 5500?

Comment: HTTP metgods are usually wrutrwn with capital letters, i.e. `"POST"` instead of `"post"`. Cannot this cause the issue?

Comment: I have changed "post" to "POST" but still to no avail. Port 5500 is obtained when I clicked the "Open with Live Server" from the HTML file in VSCode. Is it not the correct server?

Comment: That's right, VS Code's live server is for static hosting only

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59537824/how-to-run-php-with-vscode

Comment: Oh God how could I forget about running it from XAMPP!! Thank you, Phil! I don't get the 405 error anymore while running from localhost:8080, although I still can't save the canvas to database–but it really helps clear my mind a bit. The error's been haunting me for two days.

Comment: UPDATE: I got everything now. Thank you so much for your help, Phil! You're the saviour of mankind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in your php and js...

if you check it properly. in PHP

```
$image = $_POST["image"];
```

indexing image which is not define in js..

```
data: imgdata,
```

it should be

```
data: {'image' : imgdata}
```

try above changes and report back.

**UPDATE**

in your js `api/insertDrawing.php` but you didn't specified the correct php file which code belongs to this file.. did you add header content type to this file.

```
<?php

    $image = $_POST["image"];
    
    $data = Array(
        "insertStatus" => "success",
        "image" => $image,
    );
    
    echo json_encode($data);
```

above code is working perfectly by removing content type from js.

```
$.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: 'file.php',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {'image': imgdata},
      }).done(function(data) {
          console.log(data.image);
      });
```

the result is ;

```
image: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAlgA"
insertStatus: "success"
```

Comment: I update my answer but still awaiting for OP reply.

Comment: Hi, I tried correcting as you suggested but I still received the POST 405 (Method not Allowed) error. Also, how do I add header content type??

Comment: try to send ajax to server without adding to db. if send is success.. than we have to find out the error

Comment: I changed my server to xampp and the error 405 disappeared but I still can't save it to database

Comment: UPDATE: I can save the canvas link now! Thank you so much Ash!! You helped a lot!